# How to add new line in text file in output from remote shell script using plink

Tags: linux, plink

From windows i am executing a remote shell script using putty plink

```
cmd>plink.exe -ssh username@hostipd -pw gbG8qs4 /user/alice/listoffiles.sh > C:\log1.txt
```

Shell script in remote server

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "Hellow\nWorld"
```

I am getting the output in log1.txt is `HelloWorld` without any newline. How to get ouput as

```
Hello
World
```

Please help

Comment: I added my comment as a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using an editor which is not capable of the handling of *nix line endings. Use an capable editor (like Notepad2 or Notepad++, ...)

Alternatively you could replace `\n` with `\r\n` which emulates the Windows line endings. If you want to pipe any other output or want to convert a file you could use

```
sed -e 's/$/\r/' inputfile > outputfile
```

on the *nix side.